# How to get back to last add command

Tags: git

I made a mess with my code cause 'git stash apply' command. 
Now I have a big mess with conflicts.

Before this mess I made 'git add .' command.
Is there any possible way to go to the state before 'git stash apply' and after 'git add .'

Comment: `git reflog` is your friend.

Comment: Oh, but getting to the state immediately after `git add` will be tough.